# How to preload text value into SkyFloatingLabelTextField

Tags: swift, xcode, skyfloatinglabeltextfield

I am currently using SkyFloatingLabelTextField and have the following code.

```
var textFieldLastNameSignUp: SkyFloatingLabelTextField!

textFieldLastNameSignUp.placeholder = "Family Name"
textFieldLastNameSignUp.title = "Last Name"
```

Based on this it shows a single line in the app loaded with 'Family Name'. The moment I click into the field, the 'Family Name' text goes away and the title 'Last Name' shows above the entry.

I would like to show both 'Family Name' in the entry line and 'Last Name' in the title at the same time. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Describe UI what you accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

These two things did the magic.

This forced the title to be visible
    textFieldLastNameSignUp.setTitleVisible(true)

This forced the text box to accept the text
    textFieldLastNameSignUp.insertText(self.userLastName)